# how to set custom floating imagebutton in coordinates layout in android

Tags: java, android, floating-action-button

I have set custom floating movable  button with coordinate layout i have change src but prob is not change button color also i have change color but my imagebutton size decrees how to solve it.

I have create custom button using FrameLayout but this imagebutton not movable.

[image: My Image look like this]

**AddButtonCode**

```
ImageButton btnAdd = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    btnAdd.setSelected(btnAdd.isSelected() ? true : false);
    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout =
            (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_collapsing);
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(getString(R.string.sachitn));
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.flexible_example_toolbar);
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });
```

**My Code**

```
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/add_btn"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/main.appbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />
```

Comment: Could you share your `add_btn` code as well?

Comment: actually, I meant your designed button with frame layout

Comment: My designed button with floatingactionbutton in src